# Why after two requests my array is undefined? (using chart.js and stock.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

I am attempting to graph stocks using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) and [stocks.js](https://github.com/wagenaartje/stocks.js/) to graph stocks. I use two functions for this. One that is received when a button is clicked and another that cleans the data and updates the chart.

I have tried changing what is graphed, how it's updated, changing how I clean the data, as well as other things. I am new to JavaScript. When an HTML button is clicked then it activates the `oneday` function. I have other buttons that do the same thing but with different times etc. Right now it works when I press one of the buttons, then when I press another it changes, but the third has the x-axis as undefined, then the fourth has both axes as undefined.

```
function clearwithtimes(){
        async function request(){
            var result = await stocks.timeSeries({
                symbol: stock,
                interval: interval,
                amount: time
             });
             var datesdata = result;
             for (i in datesdata){
                     //Loops through array
                 delete datesdata[i].high
                 delete datesdata[i].low
                 delete datesdata[i].close
                 delete datesdata[i].volume
                 delete datesdata[i].open
             }
             var stringeddates = JSON.stringify(datesdata);
             var step;
             stringeddates = stringeddates.replace('[{"date":"', '');
             for (step = 0; step < time; step++) {
                 stringeddates = stringeddates.replace('T', ' ');
                 stringeddates = stringeddates.replace('.000Z', '');
                 stringeddates = stringeddates.replace('",', '#');
                 stringeddates = stringeddates.replace('"},{"date":"', '#');
             }
             stringeddates = stringeddates.replace('},{"date":"', '#');
             stringeddates = stringeddates.replace('T19:00:00.000Z"}]', '');
             stringeddates = stringeddates.replace('T19:00:00.000Z"', '');
             stringeddates = stringeddates.replace('"}]', '');
             stringeddates = stringeddates.split("#");

             var result = await stocks.timeSeries({
                 symbol: stock,
                 interval: interval,
                 amount: time
                });
            for (i in result){
                    //Loops through array
                delete result[i].high
                delete result[i].low
                delete result[i].close
                delete result[i].volume
                delete result[i].date
             }
         var numberlist = JSON.stringify(result);
         var step;
         numberlist = numberlist.replace('[{"open":', '');
         for (step = 0; step < time; step++) {
         numberlist = numberlist.replace('},{"open":', '#');
     }
         numberlist = numberlist.replace('},{"open":', '#');
         numberlist = numberlist.replace('}]', '');
         numberlist = numberlist.split("#");
         finalprices = numberlist.reverse();
         finaldates = stringeddates.reverse();
         stockGraph.data.datasets[0].data = finalprices;
         stockGraph.data.labels = finaldates;
         stockGraph.update();
        }
        request();
    }
    function oneday() {
        stockform=document.getElementById("stockname");
        stock=stockform.elements["Stock"].value;
        time = 96;
        interval = '15min';
        clearwithtimes();
    }
```

What should happen is when I activate the one day function multiple times the axis should not be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running up against rate limits, and neither stocks.js nor Alpha Vantage's API report any errors when that happens. Examine the XHR response when your axes go wonky:

> {
>       "Note": "Thank you for using Alpha Vantage! Our standard API call frequency is 5 calls per minute and 500 calls per day. Please visit https://www.alphavantage.co/premium/ if you would like to target a higher API call frequency."
>   }

As a rule, you should try to be a good citizen when hitting remote APIs, and don't make more requests than necessary. Your `request()` function grabs the same data twice, presumably because you destroy some of the data which you need later. Refactor the function, and you only need to hit the API once:

```
function clearwithtimes() {
  async function request() {
    const result = await stocks.timeSeries({
      symbol: stock,
      interval: interval,
      amount: time
    });

    if (result.length === 0) {
      console.log('Something went wrong!');
      return;
    }

    const finaldates = result.map(series =>
      series.date      // get the date from each series,
        .toISOString() // convert it to a string, e.g. "2019-05-11T10:10:23.323Z",
        .split('T')[0] // split it in two at the "T", and return the first half
    ).reverse();
    const finalprices = result.map(series => series.open).reverse();

    stockGraph.data.datasets[0].data = finalprices;
    stockGraph.data.labels = finaldates;
    stockGraph.update();
  }
  request();
}
```

The only way `stocks.timeSeries()` can tell you you've hit the limit is by returning an empty array. Check for that before updating your chart.

[`result.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array based on the `result` array, without modifying it. It's far preferable to trying to work with raw JSON strings.

Ideally, you should cache the value of `result` and update your chart based on that cached value whenever possible.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! Not only does this totally fix my problem but it also helped me a lot with my javascript. As a beginner Its amazing that you would do this, I appreciate it so much! Thank you for helping me :)